# Python: simple 'if' statement to tell you if the user has no windows maximized

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, desktop, tk-toolkit

i have some tkinter code that should raise the window when the user is on their desktop with no windows maximized. What code would tell me whether the user is on their desktop?(preferably without win32 but, if so please leave some directions for installing)

```
if #user is on desktop# == True or etc.:
    root.lift()
```

Comment: `== True` is redundant, but you need a question if you want help

Comment: I think you can use win32 etc for this, search google. However i think you should also ask a question, so we know what exactly your problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html). First there are a couple of [`Windll.User32`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_USER#Implementation) functions we should get to know:

- [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - Enumerates all top-level windows on the screen by passing the handle to each window, in turn, to an application-defined callback function.
- [`IsWindowVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - Determines the visibility state of the specified window.
- [`IsZoomed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) -  Determines whether a window is maximized.
- [`GetForgroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - Retrieves a handle to the foreground window (the window with which the user is currently working).
- [`GetShellWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - The return value is the handle of the Shell's desktop window. If no Shell process is present, the return value is NULL.

First things first import `ctypes`:

```
import ctypes
```

Then set up the functions we will need to call from the user32 dll:

```
EnumWindows         = ctypes.windll.user32.EnumWindows
EnumWindowsProc     = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_bool, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
IsWindowVisible     = ctypes.windll.user32.IsWindowVisible
IsZoomed            = ctypes.windll.user32.IsZoomed
GetForegroundWindow = ctypes.windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow
GetShellWindow      = ctypes.windll.user32.GetShellWindow
```

Then we can define a method that checks that there are not maximised windows and the user is on the desktop like so:

```
def desktop_active():
    MAX_WINDOWS = []  # Use this to store if any windows are maximised
    def foreach_window(hwnd, lParam):  #Callback function for Enumwindows etc
        if IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
            MAX_WINDOWS.append(IsZoomed(hwnd))
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc(foreach_window), 0)
    if any(MAX_WINDOWS):
        return False
    if GetShellWindow() == GetForegroundWindow():
        return True  # If we have no windows max'd and the forground is the desktop
```

You can then use the function in your code as requested:

```
if desktop_active():
    root.lift()
```

Credit to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) and [Johannes Sasongok](http://sjohannes.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/win32-python-getting-all-window-titles/)

Comment: Thank you so much, you have really given me some other options and helped me greatly.